# Remove all leader mappings before creating my own

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-system, leader

The question pretty much sums it up: Is there a way to clear all of the `<leader>` mappings set by plugin authors before proceeding to set my own custom mappings?

The only way I've seen to do this is to remove them individually with an `autocmd` or in the `after/` directory, but I'd like to remove them all in one go without ever having to worry about it again, regardless of the plugins I may add in the future.

Comment: You don't need to clear existing mappings before creating yours.

Comment: the question does not ask if there is a **need** to clear existing mappings, the question asked if there is a **way** to do so ... your comment is not helpful

Comment: I guess I'm just being picky about not having any mappings that I didn't put there myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `maplist()` to get a list of mappings; this returns a list with information about every custom mapping.

You can see the exact list of properties it returns in `:help maplist()`; the one important for us here is `lhs` ("left hand side"), which is the key mapping. For example for `nnoremap <Leader>tc …` it's set to `'\ts'`, assuming that `<Leader>` is the default of `\` (`<Leader>` is expanded when used, so it shows up as a backslash).

To unmap everything, you can use something like:

```
for m in maplist()
    if m.lhs[0] == '\'
        echo printf('unmap %s', m.lhs)
        exe 'unmap' .. m.lhs
    endif
endfor
```

Note that this doesn't necessarily *truly* remove all mappings, because some plugins may define buffer-specific mappings from an autocmd which will be applied every time a buffer is loaded. Unsetting those would be complex and error-prone, but you can run the above in your autocmd (although that would also remove your own mappings). In general it's probably a better strategy to configure the specific plugins, many have some sort of setting to prevent defining any mappings (and if they don't, creating a patch is usually easy, and thus far everyone I've sent a patch for this has accepted it).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for the explanation of why it's still not ideal. I suppose I could maintain my own list of mappings to check against when running the `autocmd`, if I really want to go down this route.